# how does opencv videocapture work when using url as a parameter?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, opencv

I'm currently working on a python project which has to deal with many videos on the web. Let a list of these videos url_list, i.e.

```
url_list = ['sample_url1.mp4', ..., 'sample_url_n.mp4']
```

For a performance reason, I decided to use ThreadPool to get videos asynchronously.
The code is like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import cv2

def get_video(url):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    if hasattr(cap, 'isOpened') and cap.isOpened():
        return cap


with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    caps = executor.map(get_video, url_list)

# video processing section
for cap in caps:
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            do_something_with(frame)
```

And here is my questions.

1. How exactly does `cv2.VideoCapture` work when using url as a parameter? Does it download(in memory) the whole video at once from url at the `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)` part? Or does it work like a video stream from url?

   In other words, if a network gets disconnected at video processing section, will the rest of the code work?

   (I tested it several times[disconnecting the internet at the video processing part], and it works. But I'm not 100% sure it is safe to use.)

2. Is `cv2.VideoCapture` safe for using with multithreading and multiprocessing?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
I'm using ffmpeg as a backend.

**Edit2**

I tested with a big size mp4 file and it failed the connectivity test. So I assume that VideoCapture doesn't read the whole video but just some parts of it. It will read the rest of it in `cap.read()`. If this is wrong, any correction will welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCV4 `videoio` module use multi-platform libraries such as `ffmpeg, gstreamer, Media SDK`, platform specific such as `WINRT, AVFOUNDATION, MSMF/DSHOW, V4L/V4L2` as backends to operate with files or urls. When open a file/url(`VideoCapture::open`), it will loop over all registered backends until open successfully. Take FFMPEG as example, it can read from url、hls if it implement the responding  protocols(such as RTMP ).

And `cv2.VideoCapture` is same to use multithreading, but take care to show the frames only in main thread. here is an example: [How to capture Multi camera with Opencv Multi threading (python)](https://answers.opencv.org/question/229866/how-to-capture-multi-camera-with-opencv-multi-threading-python/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm currently using FFmpeg as a backend. So, does it download the whole video already at the VideoCapture part or just some parts of it thus I should maintain the network connection to get the rest of the video after the VideoCapture part?